# I cannot add two BigDecimal objects

Tags: java

When I want to add two BigDecimal objects together

```
public void addBalanceWallet(BigDecimal balanceWallet) {
        this.balanceWallet.add(balanceWallet);
}
```

There is no effect. Additionally, the IDE shows
[image]

Why can't I add these two objects together?

Comment: BigDecimal objects are immutable. The result of the addition is returned. You could for example compute `this.balanceWallet = this.balanceWallet.add(balanceWallet);`

Comment: ... and when you add these two values together what would you like to do with the sum?

Comment: I am increasing the balance of the user's wallet. I used BigDecimal because it has high precision, but I can see that it is pointless.

Comment: Incidentally if this is for Bitcoin you don't need `BigDecimal` at all, because the total outstanding satoshis will never exceed about 2e15, which is less than a Java (signed) `long` can handle by a factor of a thousand, and any single wallet will be even less.

Comment: “Immutable” is the very first word in the [Javadoc for `BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 4):

You are not assigning the return value (which is the actual result of the addition) to anything and thus the "Result (...) is ignored" message. I guess you want to do the following:

```java
public void addBalanceWallet(BigDecimal balanceWallet) {
    this.balanceWallet = this.balanceWallet.add(balanceWallet);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to save the return value.
For example:

```
public BigDecimal addBalanceWallet(BigDecimal balanceWallet) {
        return this.balanceWallet.add(balanceWallet);
}
```

And afterwards:

```
BigDecimal addResult = this.balanceWallet.addBalanceWallet(some_big_decimal)
```